# How to map a custom object that has a field which is a custom object in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, orm

Getting lost reading hibernate docs
Question- how do I map a custom object that has a field which is a custom object. Example- Customer contains Name which has firstName midName last name

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Embeddable.html, https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#embeddables

Comment: Thanks, this helped.

Comment: In my example above, Name now has @Embeddable. This is fine if I just want to retrieve Customer objects, but how can I retrieve Name objects also?

Comment: You retrieve the customers and ask for their name. Or you write a query that only loads names from the customers. Read the manual.